# Javascript - adding timezone to date countdown

Tags: javascript

I have written a JavaScript countdown clock, it's my first actually, so I had to copy bits and bobs from websites to help me, nevertheless, it works. But I was wondering how I can add a timezone to my date? The until variable counts down the time to that date and time.

```
var until = new Date( 2012, 8 - 1, 29, 19, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [timezone-js](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js) library, example usage :

```
var dt = new timezoneJS.Date(2008, 9, 31, 11, 45, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```